# how to call nodejs comand from phpcli

Tags: php, node.js

I use Ubuntu 14.04 and install NodeJS. Now I want to call NodeJS command from phpcli, but it's not executing the command. This is my example code:

```
chdir('/var/www/html/kurento/video/');
$cmd = 'npm start';
var_dump(shell_exec($cmd));
```

Results in :
    string(87) " > kurento-one2many-call@6.2.2-dev start /var/www/html/kurento/video > node server.js "

Comment: My example code:
chdir('/var/www/html/kurento/video/');
$cmd = 'npm start';
var_dump(shell_exec($cmd));

Comment: Although this looks really senseless, you should at least show your code to hopefully hint on what you're actually trying to accomplish here.

Comment: My code only a few lines of it because this is an example of how to start nodeJS from phpcli. Can you help me?

Comment: Could it simply be a matter of path?  Try using the full path for `npm`.